# Why default value of database of environment is not same development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

I create table whose id is bigint

```
class Hoge < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :hoges, id: false do |t|
      t.column    :id,  :serial8, primary_key: true
      t.integer   :bar, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and set primary_key at model

```
class Hoge < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :id
end
```

then, I exec migration, development database is successfully created

```
Column        |            Type             |                        Modifiers
--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                     | not null default nextval('hoges_id_seq'::regclass)
 bar          | integer                     | not null
```

then, I exec "rake test"
test database is created, but it is invalid. default is 0.....

```
 Column       |            Type             |                        Modifiers
--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                     | not null default 0
 bar          | integer                     | not null
```

Why database of test environment is not same development environment?
(Database is postgres)

Comment: Are you using `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` to track your database state? Your issue suggests that Rails is having trouble dumping the structure of your table properly.

Comment: I use schema.rb to track database state

Comment: What does the section of `schema.rb` that defines your `hoges` table look like?

Comment: scherma.rb is following

create_table "hoges", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "id",             limit: 8, default: "nextval('hoges_id_seq'::regclass)", null: false
    t.integer  "bar",                                                                              null: false

Comment: I believe your issue is a variant of https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14300; namely, schema.rb does not support functions (which `nextval` is) as the `default` value for columns. I think simplest fix is to switch to structure.sql, as described [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14300#issuecomment-36909867).

Comment: I tried to use structure.sql. database of test environment is successfully migrated! thank you!
But, My application has been running long time, so, It is difficult to change from schema.rb to structure.sql....

Comment: You could try using the [schema_plus_default_expr gem](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus_default_expr), and see if that helps. I'm not sure to what degree it plugs into schema dumping (if at all), so you might have to manually hack your schema.rb file afterward to rewrite the id field as `t.column :id,  :serial8, primary_key: true, default: { expr: 'nextval('hoges_id_seq'::regclass)' }`.

Comment: Thank you! I try to this gem or hack schema.rb

Answer (score -2):

You should prepare your test database by using the command `rake db:test:prepare`